# Qt qpixmap returns null after a while

Tags: qt, symbian, qpixmap

I have an qt symbian project and I set background image  programmatically on constracter of QMainWindow. but I discover that bug, If I open and close that QMainWindow for example 15 times, pixmap I used for background returns null. I made that pixmap static at my static class which I keep some information during execution, but it does not help my situation. I will be thankfull for any help. Here is some code example

```
SettingsWindow::SettingsWindow(QWidget *parent) :
QMainWindow(parent), ui(new Ui::Settings)
{
ui->setupUi(this);
// getting screen geometry
QDesktopWidget* desktopWidget = qApp->desktop();
QRect screenGeometry = desktopWidget->screenGeometry();

ConstantVariables* pointer = ConstantVariables::CVinstance();

set image with screen geometry
QPalette* palette = new QPalette();
palette->setBrush(QPalette::Background,*(new QBrush(pointer->backGround->scaled(screenGeometry.width(),screenGeometry.height()))));
setPalette(*palette);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would have to step through the source to verify this, but one situation that causes the `QPixmap` constructor to return null is if it cannot allocate enough memory for the pixmap. (We had this problem with very large images.)

Are you successfully deallocating the memory used for the previous pixmaps? Run a memory profiler as you execute your application and see if memory is leaking.

Comment: There is some memory leak but, I don't load pixmap again and again when open that QMainWindow. I load pixmap at main and use it when QMainWindow starts. on closing QMainWindow I delete ui so there must be no memory leak I couldn't found where memory is leaking.

Comment: created qbrush may be reason of the memory leak?

Comment: Yes, I bet that is the case. Passing an image to the constructor probably makes a *copy* of the image and stores it in the QBrush instance. Since you are creating that on the heap and never deleting it or any of its parents, that's a big leak. A memory profiler (Valgrind) could confirm this.

Comment: I solve the problem but it's not about QBrush, Problem solved with changing pointer->backGround to QPixmap (from QPixmap*)